# Find $n$th number which does not contain the digit $c$

Tags: algorithms, contest-math

So, this problem is a competitive programming problem, but I find it to be quite mathematical. We write down the numbers which do not contain the digit c. Find an algorithm which finds the nth number written down. I have found a very interesting algorithm, but I do not understand why it works: if $c \ne 0$, we tranform n - 1 (since 0 is part of the series) into base 9. Now we add 1 to every digit bigger or equal than c. And this is the answer, but in base 10. Hopefully, you can see that such a question is quite Maths-related. Could you explain why this algorithm works?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You described a strictly increasing bijection $f: N^9 \rightarrow N_c$ where $N_9$ are the integers expressed in base 9 and $ N^c $ is the set of integers which do not contain the digit $c$.

**Corollary:** Accounting for $0$, the $n$th non-negative integer that doesn't contain a $c$ is $f(n-1_9)$.

Comment: It is true, but I still do not understand why the algorithm works. And how would I have come up with this during  a contest?

Comment: @andueu Did you prove the hint? The "strictly increasing" part is crucial. Once that's done, do you see why the "kth $N^9$ number will map to the kth $N_c$ number"? As to how to come up with it during the contest, it could be from experience with seeing such questions before.

Comment: I do not have a formal proof for the hint, but I can see where the surjectivity comes from. But why is it strictly increasing? If, for example, $c = 4$, then wouldn't the numbers 123 and 321 have the same image? And, if I am right, the function can't be injective, right?

Comment: Also, I would like to ask to get this out of my head: is there any relation between the representation of a number in base 10 and base 9?

Comment: @andueu A) No. $f(123) = 123$ and $f(321) = 321$. B) That is it increasing follows from the definition. Check the highest place value where they first disagree. C) No clear/immediate relationship between base 10 and 9.